# Pytorch - backward with complex numbers

Tags: pytorch, complex-numbers, autograd

I have complex data which I would like to use to train the network in the torch.
I have managed to create a net and all tensors.

However, as soon as I start training, I get the following error:
`grad can be implicitly created only for real scalar outputs but got the torch.complex64`

This happens during the call: loss.backward()

I wonder, is it possible to use the torch to perform training with complex data? If so, does anybody have experience with what has to be adjusted?

I wonder, is it possible to use the torch to perform training with complex data? If so, does anybody have experience with what has to be adjusted? Or how to reformulate the problem?